# Will plugging a USB device into a higher standard port improve data transfer rates if the max rate of the original port wasn't being reached?

Tags: usb, bandwidth

I have an external USB 3.2 gen 2 SSD that I plug into a front USB 3.0 port on my PC. Let's say that when copying files I get an average transfer speed of less than 200 MB/s.
(lower than both the theoretical 5 GB/s max bandwidth of the port, as well as the SSD's claimed 500+ MB/s read speed)

My question is, if I was to plug the drive into a USB 3.2 gen 2 port instead, would I expect to see an increase in the average transfer rate?

Or as another example, I have a USB 3.0 flash stick that when plugged into a front USB 3.0 port, often transfers files at as low as 25 MB/s. Would the use of a theoretically faster USB 3.2 gen 2 port see an increase in the stick's speed?

I don't have an easily available 3.2 gen 2 port for testing, so I Was just curious as to whether an underperforming device (in terms of both its own rated speeds as well as the max bandwidth of the slot it is in) would see a speed boost if it was plugged into a port with a higher max bandwidth.

Comment: It may depend on the device itself and its compatibility with your ports.

Comment: Hard to say. Although the max speeds will increase, it really is up to the drive and how full it is, whether or not these speeds will be reached. But it is definitely worth trying, given that you actually have a USB 3.2 gen 2 port to test it with. I don't think the speed increases will be massive though. Not enough to purchase a USB 3.2gen2 controller.

Comment: USB3 was 5Gb, note the small b. As in 5 Gigabit, not gigabytes per second. That give a theoretical 625 Megabytes per second. If you are not getting the full device speed then chances are it is your devices or cables having a problem. Many SSDs and USB sticks only tell your their maximum READ speed and fail to tell you that their writes speeds are far lower than that.

Comment: You can also only get the maximum speed supported by both sides. If your computer supports 10Gbps but your SSD only supports 5Gbps then you will only ever get the 5Gbps speed.

Comment: @LPChip, I don't have an easily available 3.2 gen 2 port for testing.
I Was essentially just curious as to whether an underperforming device (in terms of both its own rated speeds as well as the max bandwidth of the slot it is in) would see a speed boost if it was plugged into a port with a higher max bandwidth.

Comment: @TechHorse your device is performing way below what any of the USB3 standards support. Most likely it is simply that the device itself cannot work faster.  As I said earlier many devices you buy only tell you their read speed and don't bother telling you how bad their write speeds are.